# how to use d.ts file in react typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i create a react typeScript project and write a simple d.ts file ,but seems project don`t know this file

```
# mTest.d.ts

declare namespace mTest{
    let num:Number;
}
```

log it in App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


console.log('mTest',mTest);
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

why mTest is not defiend? seems that d.ts file doesn`t exit
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgDyL.png)

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The contents of `d.ts` files, and also anything to which the `declare` modifier is applied, by definition contain only type information for values that are provided elsewhere.